# What is the difference between mov al, byte ptr [esi] and mov al,[num]

Tags: masm

I have some code that works properly, but I want to know the difference between 
using `mov al, byte ptr [esi]` and `mov al,[num]`. Also why do I need to define the pointer variable to `dd` instead of define `db`. Here's the code

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 1000h

Sleep proto arg1:dword
printf proto c arg1:ptr byte, printlist:vararg


.data
array db "hello" ,0
pointerByte dd offset array
fmtmsg1 db "%c",0

.code
public main

main proc

    mov esi,pointerByte
    mov cl,0
repeat_loop:

    push ecx

    mov al,byte ptr [esi]
    invoke printf,addr fmtmsg1,al

    inc esi

    pop ecx
    inc cl
    cmp cl,5
    jne repeat_loop

    ;done


   ret
main endp

end main
```

Comment: Err, they do different things? Have you read the processor handbook?

Comment: _"why do I need to define the pointer variable to `dd` instead of define `db`?"_ Because an address won't fit in a single byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `num` is equivalent to the address stored in `esi`, there is no practical difference between the two.

You need to define the pointer variable with `dd` (data double) because you are assigning an 32-bit offset. `db` (data byte) is only for 8-bit assignments. Also, take into consideration that `dw` (data word) exists.